# How to get a list of kernel functions and their addresses/sizes, or symbol table under FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, freebsd, symbols

If I would like to get the kernel function names, addresses and sizes like "nm -S program" under Linux userspace, what can I do for FreeBSD kernel? The source can be static from files or dynamic from memory.

It seems Linux has the symbol table called "System.map", any corresponding one for FreeBSD, or what else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nm -S /boot/kernel/kernel.symbols, perhaps?